# How do you pass a job name argument to the succeeded expression function in an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

In the Azure DevOps documentation, it says that you can [pass a job name as a parameter to the `succeeded` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#succeeded), but it doesn't illustrate how to refer to a job name.

Given the following contrived pipeline, if I merely try `succeeded(first)` in the last job's condition I'm receiving a failure message that says *An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Unrecognized value: 'first'*. I can work around it by replacing that call with `in(dependencies.first.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues')` but I'm curious how to actually reference the job name in `succeeded()` such that the third job runs.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-20.04

pr: none
trigger:
  batch: true

jobs:
  - job: first
    steps:
    - script: echo hi

  - job: second
    condition: eq(true, false)
    steps:
    - script: echo hi again

  - job: third
    dependsOn:
      - first
      - second
    condition: and(
        succeeded(first),
        in(dependencies.second.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped', 'SucceededWithIssues')
      )
    steps:
      - script: echo bye
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the sample in this link [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#conditions).

In your case, please change `succeeded(first)` to `succeeded('first')`.

[image: Validation Result]

Comment: is possible to do the same with task instead of jobs?